# Shimano EX Crankset Pedals Compatibility

Tags: shimano, crankset, vintage, clipless

I recently bought an old Shimano EX crankset, which I'd like to mount new clip-on pedals to (Shimano Dura-Ace PD-R9100).

Does anyone have any experience with using new clip-on pedals on vintage cranks?

Thank you,

Fynn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure pedal axle/spindle size?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42039/how-to-measure-pedal-axle-spindle-size)

Comment: Apart from some rare old French pedals and one-off Shimano 1 inch Dura Ace pedals, pedals will fit any type of crank.

Comment: @Carel at least Dura-Ace EX and 600 EX had those oddball pedals. On the other hand, there are some models with "EX" that have standard pedal threads, so unless the question is updated with photos it's better to measure. Anyway, there are adapters from the inch thread to standard thread.